# Connecting To A Git Repository through its URL using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, git, version-control

I'm new to Git.
I need to connect to a git repository using its URL and get information of that git repository in my ASP.NET application.

Comment: ...and what have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried GitSharp but it connect to local Git repositories only.

Answer (score 1):

If you are connecting to GitHub, you can use GitHub for windows.   http://windows.github.com/

Answer (score 0):

[Git Extensions](http://code.google.com/p/gitextensions/) integrates it with Visual Studio, but I just use Git Bash that comes with [Github for Windows](http://windows.github.com/) as @Lain mentioned as I wanted to get used to using the command shell.

Using command line with Git is very easy, mainly because you won't get the horrible merge and update problems that you will get with Subversion, so the need for a Visual Studio addin is really negligible.

Answer (score 0):

> I tried GitSharp but it connect to local Git repositories only.

git and mercurial are distributed and decentralized. There is no "server"; your local clone *is the server*. github just provides a web interface and another server to back up your repositories too.

To get information on any git repository - you'll have to clone it locally. If you are only concerned about github, you can use the [github api](http://developer.github.com/v3/) to get information about repositories that are hosted with them.

This will only work for repositories hosted on github; and not on other git repositories.